# Preciso de soporte en shopify con un error en la plantilla de email marketing

Tags: email, shopify, liquid

Tengo un bloque de código liquid en mi plantilla de correo electrónico de marketing automatizado en shopify y necesito que a través de código se muestre el nombre de los productos que el cliente ha comprado.
[image: Email Template Screenshot]

He probado con el código que se muestra en la imagen adjunta pero no funciona, no se muestra nada en el email.

Comment: La propia imagen te responde... `unknown liquid variable on line 1`. Con lo que se ve en tu imagen, no podemos hacer ni saber nada más. Por cierto... el código es texto, no imagen, la regla es tratarlo como tal